# How to change file version, product and copy right values for .exe generated through electron framework

Tags: npm, electron

I have built an electron app, this must be able change electron file version, product version and copy right to the value I specify when package is generated. I generating the package using electron package for windows and linux. How to do this?

I see npm package rcedit is somehow linked to this, I am not sure how to use this package? I want these values to be set during electron package.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you are using the [Electron Packager](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager) command line tool to package your application, please refer to its [API Documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md) page to learn about all the available options:

> **buildVersion**
>
> String
>
> The build version of the application. Defaults to the value of
>   appVersion. Maps to the `FileVersion` metadata property on Windows, and
>   `CFBundleVersion` on macOS.
>
> **appVersion**
>
> String
>
> The release version of the application. By default the `version`
>   property in the `package.json` is used but it can be overridden with
>   this argument. If neither are provided, the version of Electron will
>   be used. Maps to the `ProductVersion` metadata property on Windows, and
>   `CFBundleShortVersionString` on macOS.
>
> **appCopyright**
>
> String
>
> The human-readable copyright line for the app. Maps to the
>   `LegalCopyright` metadata property on Windows, and
>   `NSHumanReadableCopyright` on macOS.

To achieve what you're asking for, you can for instance add the following options to the relevant `electron-packager` command in your `package.json` file:

- `--buildVersion='Build 42'`
- `--appVersion='Version 3.14'`
- `--appCopyright='My Own Private Copyright'`

Comment: Hi Libera Me thats perfect I also want to change file description

Comment: @karansys Please search for `FileDescription` in the above-mentioned API Documentation page; the relevant option is probably `win32metadata`, but I cannot test it myself, since I'm on macOS...

Comment: That would be something like: `--win32metadata.FileDescription='My App Description'`.

Comment: @LiberaMe, is it possible to read the buildVersion in the app? I can get the version with `app.getVersion()` but not the buildVersion.